# Java: Distingushing between end of one message and end of the stream

Tags: java, io, eof

I'm writing a small program writing to the command line, using SSH, and therefore usually getting output after some input.

So now I'm reading that output like this:

```
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int character;
            try {
                while ((character = output.read()) != -1) {
                    string += character;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

So far, I'm controlling the end of the stream. However, I would like to be able to estimate the end of one message (which doesn't have to be just one line) by which I mean the remote output to the sent input, respectively.

Is there a possibility to do this?

For instance, when I login via SSH, I send the command "ssh user@server", and now that reading thread should only read the "user@server's password:" message and then free the object's lock so that the writing stream can go on. But I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It is a byte-stream. If you want messages, you have to define and implement them yourself. In some simple cases, a line is a message. As you've said that isn't the case here, it is up to you to define.

Comment: Thanks so far. Well then. But is there not any way to estimate the remotely replying output to one remotely received input, in TCP?

Else, how could I implement it, for instance? Not in Java, right?

What I, of course, could do, is to set a timeout for the blocking method, but that would just be a poor excuse for synchronizing...

Comment: @TrojanWhoresProcurer SSH isn't really a messaging case at all. There are streams in both directions and input can appear on either of them at any time. You should use a separate thread for reading from SSH.

Comment: I do use a separate thread for reading. The thing is that I don't always know the format of the "replys" which can be from various programs, returning different results, or errors. Otherwise, it would be easy to "define" such a message. But in this case, it seems quite impossible, then... I'll have no other choice but to inelegantly put a timeout to the reading thread...

Comment: You don't need to know the format. You just need to read the input as you get it, and send it to wherever its supposed  to go.

Comment: Yes, but it's not always that simple. At least, that's what it seems like to me. It's not only the format, it's also the length, and the time. A process or thread could take longer breaks between lines, and often, one wants to know which process or thread it comes from; especially when one sends via several processes or threads to that remote machine. I guess, one needs different solutions then. Thanks anyway!